# Is iLuv USB Audio Adapter supported in Linux?

Tags: soundcard

Is [iLuv USB Audio Adapter](http://smile.amazon.com/iLuv-USB-Audio-Adapter-iCB758WHT/dp/B007PFZEKY) supported in Linux?

It's a portable USB audio card that takes no more space and costs hardly more than an [adapter](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16812200956).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I got one today - it said "PC Compatible" but no mention of Windows, so I figured I would give the company a hard time if it did not work (even though it was less than $10)
I had to go into sound settings and change it over - it is listed as "Audio Adapter (Planet UP 100, Genius G-Talk) Analog Stereo."

I have not tried using it for input, but it works just fine for output.

I am on Ubuntu 12.0.4 if that makes any difference...